# Keyword `new` in combination with `auto`

Tags: c++, casting, new-operator, auto

What does

`new (&as_string) auto(other.as_string);`

do where `as_string` is an `std::string` object?
I see that `auto(other.as_string)` constructs a new copy of `other.as_string` but what does the `(&as_string)` causes in combination with the new?

Comment: Where did you come across it? Can you provide more context?

Comment: @PeteBecker - The OP needs to clarify, but it seems like code form an implementation of a tagged union that contains a `std::string` member.

Comment: @StoryTeller - shrug. There are lots of things it could be.

Comment: @PeteBecker - True. But I think the language being used sort of implies it. Regardless, I'm more amazed with the use of `auto` here. A [toy example](https://ideone.com/AWdd8q) builds fine on GCC, and I wish the question was about *that*.